# Python3: How to show "stopwatch" style time of long running blackbox function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a script that includes an external library which contains a long running function.

e.g.

```
import some_api
print("Running task X with parameters Y...")
someapi.long_task(my_data)
```

I was thinking it would be nice to have a timer appended to the end of the line that shows the current elapsed seconds i.e. a count-up time as opposed to a count-down timer, not only so you know something is happening with feedback on the time taken. Right now I'm just displaying total elapsed time at the end of the completion of the function.

I can and will use a spinner which I'm fine with but after combing through various progress bar libraries and timing libraries I'm no closer to an answer.

Ideally I'd like to get to something like:

```
Run 1 ended in 450 seconds
Run 2 running. Time far 230s
```

Comment: Use a `global` variable that you can keep overriding from inside the function that has the time elapsed or time left. You can then use this variable to plot/show the spinner or progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a pretty hacky solution for python 3.6+ (see `function_progress1`).  Essentially, you can run a thread that will print out the progress every `prog_notify` seconds while the main thread runs the function.  I didn't add keyword function support, so you would have to implement it yourself.  It also prints on more than one line, which isn't super elegant. Here's a place to start though:

```
import time
import threading

def function_progress(func, args=None, prog_notify=10):
    def wait(prog_notify, stop):
        time_elapsed = 0
        start = time.time()
        while not stop():
            if time.time() - start > prog_notify:
                print(f"{func.__name__} time elapsed: {time_elapsed}")
                time_elapsed += time.time() - start
                start = time.time()

    stop = False    
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=wait, args=(prog_notify,lambda: stop))
    t1.start()
    if args:
        res = func(*args)
    else:
        res = func()
    stop = True
    t1.join()
    return res

def test0():
    time.sleep(7)
    print("no args")
    time.sleep(5)
    print("no args")
    return 0

def test1(x1):
    time.sleep(7)
    print(x1)
    time.sleep(5)
    print(x1)
    return x1 + x1

zero = function_progress(test0, prog_notify=2)
six = function_progress(test1,args=(3,),prog_notify=5)
print(zero, six)
```

The output of the tests is as follows:

```
test0 time elapsed: 0
test0 time elapsed: 2.0000417232513428
test0 time elapsed: 4.000088930130005
no args
test0 time elapsed: 6.000133037567139
test0 time elapsed: 8.000176191329956
test0 time elapsed: 10.00021767616272
no args
test1 time elapsed: 0
3
test1 time elapsed: 5.00003981590271
3
0 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `global` variable that you can keep overriding from inside the function that has the time elapsed or time left. You can then use this variable to plot/show the spinner or progress bar.